# What can be safely attached to a gas furnace cabinet?

Tags: hvac, furnace, safety, central-heating, fire-safety

The gas furnace in my house is in my laundry room about 3 inches from a stacked washer and dryer.

As such, my laundry room is short on space, so I had the thought I could add some organization by using the furnace itself. But I'm not sure if this is safe.

A few things I've thought about attaching to or placing on the furnace:

- magnetic racks that can hold a few pounds
- a box of wool dryer balls
- cleaning agents (bleach, wood cleaner, 409, etc)
- cleaning tools (broom, mop, etc)
- box of dryer sheets

What I'm looking to find out:

1. How safe is it for these items to be placed on or attached to the furnace?
2. Are any of these items at risk of causing a fire during normal operation of the heating part of the system?
3. Will these items (especially the magnets) interfere with the furnace?
4. For future reference, what kinds of materials and items should absolutely not be attached?

Gas Furnace Info: [Carrier Performance Boost 90](https://www.webhvac.com/2010/12/carrier-performance-boost-90-gas-furnace-review/)

[image: gas furnace]

Comment: What type of HVAC unit are we talking about here? A gas or oil furnace? A heat pump indoor unit with electric resistance coils?  A hydronic air handler unit?  A boiler?  If it is a combustion unit, does it source its combustion air from inside the laundry room or from a pipe to the outside?

Comment: Make & model of the equipment that you want to hang things one would be the best bet.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion and risk tolerance. The furnace model is irrelevant. Manufacturer specs don't address utility shelving attachment and probably specifically prohibit stacking random crap on it.

Comment: FYI, "HVAC system" includes ducts, vents, etc. You're just asking about your furnace cabinet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions. I've added make and model and specified gas. I'm new to owning a furnace so I didn't know there were so many possible things to add. How can I check if it's electric resistance, hydronic air, a boiler? How can I check where the combustion air is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

The external surfaces of the furnace and ductwork are not hot enough to be a fire hazard with the items you listed. As we don’t know if this is a newer sealed combustion system or older gas vented system you would need to stay away from a vent they can be hot.
I would not hang heavy items like gallons of anything even if magnets could hold them the duct’s are not designed for this but light loads I don’t see a problem.

I probably would not put even 409 or any chemicals there I had one customer that used the main trunk line to the registers as a shelf. The heat cool cycles caused spray bottles to dribble when the heat was running the air in the bottles expanded dribbled on the duct and one of the bottles had a cleaner  that dissolved the galvanized coating and it started rusting. (My guess it was a slightly acidic cleaner as even vinegar will dissolve galvanized coatings).
I was able to clean the rust and use cold galvanizing spray to stop the rust she then put the stuff on a raised tray and that stopped the dribbling.
You don’t want stuff dribbling down the side.
I don’t see a problem with dryer balls anti static sheets or hanging a broom by magnets and would not expect any problems because of the magnets.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to have anything close to a furnace. Our church got warned by the insurance inspector that nothing may touch the furnace and "stuff " should be a few inches away. Because they were in a large closet-like room people just stored stuff in it ,some touching the HVAC. These were two large capacity gas furnaces plus AC units as one would have in a large home.